# autoHideDuration not work with change on state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to decide if i activate autohide duration after some process

in FC component using hooks to manage state

```
 <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={isLoading ? 500 : null}
        onClose={(e: any, reason: string) => {
          handleClose(e, reason);
        }}
>
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code. It’s better to look at all code affected.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using **state** like this:

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
    }
  }

  // some code that changes the state to *true*

  <Snackbar
    anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: 'bottom',
    horizontal: 'center',
    }}
    open={open}
    autoHideDuration={this.state.isLoading ? 500 : null}
    onClose={(e: any, reason: string) => {
    handleClose(e, reason);
    }}
  >

}
```

Comment: do you know why it is not possible to set the autoHideDuration dynamically like ``autoHideDuration={variable.duration}´´ or something

Comment: @FuzzyTemper strange... acording to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/) it should work as long as `{variable.duration}` returns a number